# How can autocomplete in powershell from my characters that entered

Tags: powershell

I have custom command and I need to apply autocomplete for some values by take my character and find the values that have these characters

ex:

```
$customName= {
    param ($commandName, $parameterName, $wordToComplete, $commandAst, $fakeBoundParams)
    ('abcd', 'efg') | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "$WordToComplete*" } | ForEach-Object { "$_" }
}

Register-ArgumentCompleter -CommandName xstart -ParameterName blueprintName -ScriptBlock $customName
```

I need when enter
`xstart ab` and click tab then complete it to abcd

Comment: Are you running into an issue with that code?

Comment: yes, it shows abcd or efg but it is not complete when entering `xstart ab` and the tab not show anything

Comment: strings don't have a `.Name` property

Comment: It is fixed Thank you!